# How to add useEffect hook in nextjs with antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

This is my first project in next.js, I am trying to add an existing `ProLayout` component from the `ant design` library
I understand that the error I am getting is because my app is being rendered on the server side, right at that moment the `dom` does not exist, for that reason you don't get the `document` because it does not exist.

I understand that.
What I don't understand is how to implement the `useEffect` hook inside the component because `document` is inside the return

Error:

```js
Server Error
ReferenceError: document is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/pages/index.tsx (349:14) @ document

  347 | return [
  348 |   props.layout !== "side" &&
> 349 |   document.body.clientWidth > 1400 ? (
      |  ^
  350 |     <SearchInput />
  351 |   ) : undefined,
  352 |   <InfoCircleFilled key="InfoCircleFilled" />,
```

### What I need:

I need to implement useEffect inside `Index`

### Index

```js
import {
  CaretDownFilled,
  DoubleRightOutlined,
  GithubFilled,
  InfoCircleFilled,
  LogoutOutlined,
  PlusCircleFilled,
  QuestionCircleFilled,
  SearchOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons";
import type { ProSettings } from "@ant-design/pro-components";
import {
  PageContainer,
  ProCard,
  ProConfigProvider,
  ProLayout,
  SettingDrawer,
} from "@ant-design/pro-components";
import { css } from "@emotion/css";
import {
  Button,
  Divider,
  Input,
  Dropdown,
  Popover,
  theme,
} from "antd";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import defaultProps from "./_defaultProps";

const Item: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = (props) => {
  const { token } = theme.useToken();
  return (
    <div
      className={css`
        color: ${token.colorTextSecondary};
        font-size: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 22px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        &:hover {
          color: ${token.colorPrimary};
        }
      `}
      style={{
        width: "33.33%",
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
      <DoubleRightOutlined
        style={{
          marginInlineStart: 4,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const List: React.FC<{
  title: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}> = (props) => {
  const { token } = theme.useToken();

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        ...props.style,
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          fontSize: 16,
          color: token.colorTextHeading,
          lineHeight: "24px",
          fontWeight: 500,
          marginBlockEnd: 16,
        }}
      >
        {props.title}
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
        }}
      >
        {new Array(6).fill(1).map((_, index) => {
          return <Item key={index}>具体的解决方案-{index}</Item>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const MenuCard = () => {
  const { token } = theme.useToken();
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Divider
        style={{
          height: "1.5em",
        }}
        type="vertical"
      />
      <Popover
        placement="bottom"
        overlayStyle={{
          width: "calc(100vw - 24px)",
          padding: "24px",
          paddingTop: 8,
          height: "307px",
          borderRadius: "0 0 6px 6px",
        }}
        content={
          <div style={{ display: "flex", padding: "32px 40px" }}>
            <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <List title="金融解决方案" />
              <List
                title="其他解决方案"
                style={{
                  marginBlockStart: 32,
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div
              style={{
                width: "308px",
                borderInlineStart: "1px solid " + token.colorBorder,
                paddingInlineStart: 16,
              }}
            >
              <div
                className={css`
                  font-size: 14px;
                  color: ${token.colorText};
                  line-height: 22px;
                `}
              >
                热门产品
              </div>
              {new Array(3).fill(1).map((name, index) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    key={index}
                    className={css`
                      border-radius: 4px;
                      padding: 16px;
                      margin-top: 4px;
                      display: flex;
                      cursor: pointer;
                      &:hover {
                        background-color: ${token.colorBgTextHover};
                      }
                    `}
                  >
                    <img src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/antfincdn/6FTGmLLmN/bianzu%25252013.svg" />
                    <div
                      style={{
                        marginInlineStart: 14,
                      }}
                    >
                      <div
                        className={css`
                          font-size: 14px;
                          color: ${token.colorText};
                          line-height: 22px;
                        `}
                      >
                        Ant Design
                      </div>
                      <div
                        className={css`
                          font-size: 12px;
                          color: ${token.colorTextSecondary};
                          line-height: 20px;
                        `}
                      >
                        杭州市较知名的 UI 设计语言
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <div
          style={{
            color: token.colorTextHeading,
            fontWeight: 500,
            cursor: "pointer",
            display: "flex",
            gap: 4,
            paddingInlineStart: 8,
            paddingInlineEnd: 12,
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
          className={css`
            &:hover {
              background-color: ${token.colorBgTextHover};
            }
          `}
        >
          <span> 企业级资产中心</span>
          <CaretDownFilled />
        </div>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
};

const SearchInput = () => {
  const { token } = theme.useToken();
  return (
    <div
      key="SearchOutlined"
      aria-hidden
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginInlineEnd: 24,
      }}
      onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <Input
        style={{
          borderRadius: 4,
          marginInlineEnd: 12,
          backgroundColor: token.colorBgTextHover,
        }}
        prefix={
          <SearchOutlined
            style={{
              color: token.colorTextLightSolid,
            }}
          />
        }
        placeholder="搜索方案"
        bordered={false}
      />
      <PlusCircleFilled
        style={{
          color: token.colorPrimary,
          fontSize: 24,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


const Index = ():JSX.Element => {
  const [settings, setSetting] = useState<
    Partial<ProSettings> | undefined
  >({
    fixSiderbar: true,
    layout: "mix",
    splitMenus: true,
  });

  const [pathname, setPathname] = useState(
    "/list/sub-page/sub-sub-page1"
  );
  const [num, setNum] = useState(40);

    // 
    // useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
      // page loaded
      document.title = `page loaded!`;
    });
  
  return (
    <div
      id="test-pro-layout"
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    >
      <ProConfigProvider hashed={false}>
        <ProLayout
          prefixCls="my-prefix"
          bgLayoutImgList={[
            {
              src: "https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i2/O1CN01O4etvp1DvpFLKfuWq_!!6000000000279-2-tps-609-606.png",
              left: 85,
              bottom: 100,
              height: "303px",
            },
            {
              src: "https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i2/O1CN01O4etvp1DvpFLKfuWq_!!6000000000279-2-tps-609-606.png",
              bottom: -68,
              right: -45,
              height: "303px",
            },
            {
              src: "https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/O1CN018NxReL1shX85Yz6Cx_!!6000000005798-2-tps-884-496.png",
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              width: "331px",
            },
          ]}
          {...defaultProps}
          location={{
            pathname,
          }}
          siderMenuType="group"
          menu={{
            collapsedShowGroupTitle: true,
          }}
          avatarProps={{
            src: "https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/antfincdn/efFD%24IOql2/weixintupian_20170331104822.jpg",
            size: "small",
            title: "七妮妮",
            render: (props, dom) => {
              return (
                <Dropdown
                  menu={{
                    items: [
                      {
                        key: "logout",
                        icon: <LogoutOutlined />,
                        label: "退出登录",
                      },
                    ],
                  }}
                >
                  {dom}
                </Dropdown>
              );
            },
          }}
          actionsRender={(props) => {
            if (props.isMobile) return [];
            return [
              props.layout !== "side" &&
              document.body.clientWidth > 1400 ? (
                <SearchInput />
              ) : undefined,
              <InfoCircleFilled key="InfoCircleFilled" />,
              <QuestionCircleFilled key="QuestionCircleFilled" />,
              <GithubFilled key="GithubFilled" />,
            ];
          }}
          headerTitleRender={(logo, title, _) => {
            const defaultDom = (
              <a>
                {logo}
                {title}
              </a>
            );
            if (document.body.clientWidth < 1400) {
              return defaultDom;
            }
            if (_.isMobile) return defaultDom;
            return (
              <>
                {defaultDom}
                <MenuCard />
              </>
            );
          }}
          menuFooterRender={(props) => {
            if (props?.collapsed) return undefined;
            return (
              <div
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  paddingBlockStart: 12,
                }}
              >
                <div>© 2021 Made with love</div>
                <div>by Ant Design</div>
              </div>
            );
          }}
          onMenuHeaderClick={(e) => console.log(e)}
          menuItemRender={(item, dom) => (
            <div
              onClick={() => {
                setPathname(item.path || "/welcome");
              }}
            >
              {dom}
            </div>
          )}
          {...settings}
        >
          <PageContainer
            token={{
              paddingInlinePageContainerContent: num,
            }}
            extra={[
              <Button key="3">操作</Button>,
              <Button key="2">操作</Button>,
              <Button
                key="1"
                type="primary"
                onClick={() => {
                  setNum(num > 0 ? 0 : 40);
                }}
              >
                主操作
              </Button>,
            ]}
            subTitle="简单的描述"
            footer={[
              <Button key="3">重置</Button>,
              <Button key="2" type="primary">
                提交
              </Button>,
            ]}
          >
            <ProCard
              style={{
                height: "200vh",
                minHeight: 800,
              }}
            >
              <div />
            </ProCard>
          </PageContainer>

          <SettingDrawer
            pathname={pathname}
            enableDarkTheme
            getContainer={() =>
              document.getElementById("test-pro-layout")
            }
            settings={settings}
            onSettingChange={(changeSetting) => {
              setSetting(changeSetting);
            }}
            disableUrlParams={false}
          />
        </ProLayout>
      </ProConfigProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

### Links:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eoy3s9

https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/layout?tab=api

Comment: Please check it's rendering server side or client side, on server side document will not work,